# VB.NET pass null SQL date as time in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, plsql

I am writing a VB.NET application that moves data from a MS SQL database table to an Oracle database table.

A record in the MS SQL DB has a null date.  The Oracle db table column is set to allow nulls.  When I run the VB.NET application and step through the app, everything works fine until the record with the null date.  VB.NET shows the null date as '12:00 AM' with no date, just the time.

The Oracle error I get is: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Here is the SQL to pull in the date from the MS SQL DB:

```
convert(varchar(10),DATE_COLUMN,101) end as 'DATE_COLUMN'
```

Here is the PL/SQL I have for inserting into the Oracle DB:

```
to_date('" & tmp_DATE_COLUMN & "','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `tmp_something_DATE` variable is of type `Date`. Problem is that it cannot store `NULL/Nothing` values in a `Date` variable. If you try to assign a `Date` to Nothing, it is really assigned to `Date.MinValue`, which equals to `#12:00:00 AM#`. You either need `Nullable(Of Date)` or use `DataTable` column values directly.